# 3rd party framework compile warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode9.2

Working with this team and I need to release next build to app store. After cloning project I have 37 compile warnings. Should I bring this to someones attention, fix these myself, or leave as is? How would I handle the warnings from 3rd party frameworks Unlock the file and fix myself? id rather not make changes to the 'socketEngine.swift` file that I don't know how works.

Below I've listed the types of warnings I'm getting. 
- "characters is deprecated, please use storing or substring directly", and various other deprecations. 
- "when calling this function in swift 4 or later, you must pass a `()` tuple.
- "This block declaration is not a prototype" - About 30 of these

When I run the app everything runs smoothly. 
This project is objective-c and Im much better with swift so I don't want correct all of these changes at the moment if I don't need to.

Comment: "Should I bring this to someones attention, fix these myself, or leave as is?"  Huh!?  Why don't you discuss it with your team, first?

Comment: Well the deprecations will work for now but the warnings are to tell you that they really need to be changed to newer methods or you may suffer issues in forthcoming iOS versions.  As for this 'Should I bring this to someones attention, fix these myself, or leave as is?' it's not something anyone other than you and your team can decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warnings do not prevent you from building and releasing an app. You *can* ignore the warnings.

What you *should* do is talk to your team and ask about any warnings that are part of their code. Why not talk to a teammate?

Do not unlock the files. If you are using a dependency manager, your edits may be lost and need to be repeated in the next release.